# Web Site Availability in Windows Azure

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [App pool timeout for azure web sites](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10943111/app-pool-timeout-for-azure-web-sites)

I am working on an asp.net mvc 4 app that is hosted in Windows Azure. This app will not have a lot of traffic as people will intermittently (once an hour) use it. I wanted to try using Windows Azure.

My app is currently set to use the FREE web site mode. I noticed that after 30 minutes, the site takes a long-time (> 5 seconds) to load. After that initial load, its fast. Then, if someone doesn't use it for another 30 minutes, it takes >5 seconds to load again.

I then tried upping the web site mode to a SHARED instance. I experienced the same problem there.

I then tried upping the web site mode to a RESERVED instance. The problem then goes away.

While I'd like to use Windows Azure, paying $50+ a month for a RESERVED instance is pretty  expensive for a site that few have used up to this point. However, I can't have the initial lag. That will just defer the few users I have. You could say you get what you pay for. At the same time, I have a hard time believing others are experiencing this problem and not complaining. There has to be something I'm missing.

I figure the problem has to deal with the application pool resetting. However, I can't seem to figure a way around this. Is anyone familiar with this issue? Is there a way to fix it on a FREE or SHARED instance?

Thank you!

Comment: Try creating an availability ping test against the app that runs more often than every 30 minutes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is expected behavior based on how Windows Azure Web Sites work.  The app pool they live in is spun up "on demand" and then hangs around for a time period.

For a detailed (and shameless plug) you can check out my article on this: http://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/.net-framework/windows-azure-websites-%e2%80%93-a-new-hosting-model-for-windows-azure/

In summary:

Web Sites are hosted in a process on a farm of machines running IIS.  If a site is idle for some time then the process is torn down automatically.  Also, if the box is seeing a lot of pressure due to the other sites on the box the idle timeout may come down quite a bit (even as low as five minutes).  When the next call comes in you'll see the process spun up again (likely on a completely different server).  This is because you are in a shared environment (and is similar to how Heroku works).  Once you move to reserved then you are the ONLY person on that virtual machine and if you suffer from noisy neighbor issues in processing its' because of your own stuff.

There are ways to keep your site "up", such as having a job that pings the url frequently; however, given that the idle timeout is somewhat fluid it may not solve every case.  You can check out a recent post by Sandrino on how to use Azure Mobile Services as a job scheduler: http://fabriccontroller.net/blog/posts/job-scheduling-in-windows-azure/ .  There are also 3rd party services available that can do the ping for you automatically.

To be honest, the web sites are a great feature for quick development and test, or even relatively low traffic sites as you are talking about.  If you need a high level of uptime and better performance then you'll want to look at Reserved, or another option if the cost isn't in line with expectations.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't an Azure problem.  It is a "feature" of any web site hosted in IIS.  The default time-out for app pools is 20 minutes.  Read about App Pool timeouts here - http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771956(v=ws.10).aspx - one method is to create a keep alive page and ping the page every 10 minutes or so.

Comment: Windows Azure Web Sites have a twist to the usual IIS Idle timeout.  Since it is a shared environment the idle timeout is fluid, meaning it can change depending on load on the host system, etc. Viperguynaz's comment about using a ping utility is still viable though, but remember that the idle timeout can be as low as 5 minutes currently, though likely higher.